# Why does this if statement not behave as I'd expect?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I am making a program that will evaluate the value of something. I have a variable that holds the total value to be added, `rcoverE`. When I test "y" for the second question, it works, but when I put in "n", it adds 5 anyway. Why is this happening?

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        int year, yearE, rcoverE;
        string rcover, func;
        cout << "Enter the decade your thing was produced (eg. 20):";
        cin >> year;
        cout << "Does you typewriter have original thingy? (y,n):";
        cin >> rcover;

        rcoverE = 0;
        if(rcover == "y" || "Y"){
           rcoverE = rcoverE + 5;
        }else{
            rcoverE = rcoverE + 0;
        }
        cout << rcoverE;
        yearE = 100 - year / 2;

    }
```

Comment: Uh, man, read a C++ book. "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."

Comment: @H2CO3 has made a good point! What about "minimal understanding" in relation to the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(rcover == "y" || "Y")
```

Does not evaluate the way you think it does.  This actually evaluates as if ("rcover == 'y') or if('Y')", not "rcover == ('y' || 'Y')."  In some languages the compiler would not let you do this, but in C++, simply putting in the statement "Y" returns true.  You need to change the statement to:

```
if(rcover == "y" || rcover == "Y")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(rcover == "y" || "Y"){
```

This condition is wrong it should be:

```
if(rcover == "y" || rcover == "Y"){
```

This: `if(rcover == "y" || "Y"){` is logically equivalent to `if(rcover == "y" || "Y" != 0)` and `"Y" !=` 0 is always true.

Comment: I think that was me.  I answered this, then before submitting, @Borgleader your answer came through.  I voted it up then saw the question getting voted down so the upvote seemed pointless.  I hit the down arrow to remove the upvote (which immediately switched it to a downvote) so then I rehit the downvote to remove it.  Wow time moves fast on SO.  :-)  Upvoted.

Comment: @moodboom if it was you can you at least remove the downvote? I'm not asking for an upvote, but since the answer isnt wrong I'd at least not want the downvote.

Comment: @moodboom Well I'm still at +2/-1 so it was somebody else. Thanks for the upvote though :)